# How to inject bash command into inline-python?

Tags: python, bash, rest, curl, dockerfile

I'm currently writing a dockerfile, in which the project's lines of code shall be counted via [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc), and sent to a server. The server is providing a RESTful API. From this API I want to get a Data-Transfer-Object, modify it and send it back to the same API to update it.
Since the runner does not memorize variables over more than one line, I (probably) have to put everything into one line (except the static API):

`ENV API=http://example-url.com/api/datapoints/`

My curl command that I go so far is this:

```sh
RUN curl 
    -d (curl -s ${API} | python3 -c "import sys, json; 
                                     newDatapointDTO=json.load(sys.stdin); 
                                     newDatapointDTO['metric']="`cloc ./src/ --json`"; 
                                     print(newDatapointDTO)") 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -X PUT ${API}
```

The problem here is that the runner does not like the interruption of the python command in order to set in a variable from bash.. So how do I insert `cloc ./src/ --json` then into Python?

I also think the command is a bit too complicated - there should be probably a better solution for this...

Comment: BTW, it's a _really_ bad idea to be using command substitutions to inject values into your Python code. Any parameters you need to pass in should use `sys.argv` or `os.environ` -- those approaches don't risk shell injection attacks.

Comment: Also, don't close your double quotes before starting a command substitution; that substitution should be quoted unless you want string-splitting and globbing to take place on its results.

Comment: Also, are you sure your original code _actually worked_? The way you have the Python indented I'd expect would cause an `IndentationError`.

Comment: There is nothing like my _original code_ since I build it for the first time, and this was the best method I could think of without knowing the syntax for dockerfile that good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting your command to JSON using `jq -Rs . <<'EOF'`, pasting your command, and then `EOF` gives us:

```
RUN ["bash", "-c", "curl \n    -d (curl -s ${API} | python3 -c \"import sys, json; \n                                     newDatapointDTO=json.load(sys.stdin); \n                                     newDatapointDTO['metric']=\"`cloc ./src/ --json`\"; \n                                     print(newDatapointDTO)\") \n    -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \n    -X PUT ${API}\n"]
```

Taking out the extra whitespace and fixing up the quoting makes that:

```
RUN ["bash", "-c", "curl -d (curl -s ${API} | python3 -c \"import sys, json;\nnewDatapointDTO=json.load(sys.stdin);\nnewDatapointDTO['metric']=$(cloc ./src/ --json);print(newDatapointDTO)\") -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X PUT ${API}"]
```

However, because that code is using shell injection to insert data into Python, it's still a Really Bad Idea. A saner version of your Python code might instead look like:

```py
import sys, json, subprocess
newDatapointDTO=json.load(sys.stdin)
newDatapointDTO['metric'] = subprocess.run(['cloc', './src/', '--json'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
print(newDatapointDTO)
```

...so wrapping that in a shell command might look like:

```
pythonScript="import sys, json, subprocess
newDatapointDTO=json.load(sys.stdin)
newDatapointDTO['metric'] = subprocess.run(['cloc', './src/', '--json'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
print(newDatapointDTO)"

curl -d "$(curl -s "$API" | python -c "$pythonScript")" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -X PUT "$API"
```

...so, generating a JSON encoding of a command line that calls that would look like:

```sh
jq -Rs . <<'EOF'
pythonScript="import sys, json, subprocess
newDatapointDTO=json.load(sys.stdin)
newDatapointDTO['metric'] = subprocess.run(['cloc', './src/', '--json'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
print(newDatapointDTO)"

curl -d "$(curl -s "$API" | python -c "$pythonScript")" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -X PUT "$API"
EOF
```

...which gives us the output:

```json
"pythonScript=\"import sys, json, subprocess\nnewDatapointDTO=json.load(sys.stdin)\nnewDatapointDTO['metric'] = subprocess.run(['cloc', './src/', '--json'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout\nprint(newDatapointDTO)\"\n\ncurl -d \"$(curl -s \"$API\" | python -c \"$pythonScript\")\" \\\n     -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \\\n     -X PUT \"$API\"\n"
```

...so we know you can put in your Dockerfile the following:

```
RUN ["bash", "-c", "pythonScript=\"import sys, json, subprocess\nnewDatapointDTO=json.load(sys.stdin)\nnewDatapointDTO['metric'] = subprocess.run(['cloc', './src/', '--json'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout\nprint(newDatapointDTO)\"\n\ncurl -d \"$(curl -s \"$API\" | python -c \"$pythonScript\")\" \\\n     -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \\\n     -X PUT \"$API\"\n"]
```

Comment: Wow, THAT is effort :D Thank you very much so far, I cannot check if it gives the right result yet, but it already passes the pipeline, what is good! I'll let you know as soon as I know more.
Is there a benefit in writing the Python script extra and not directly in the command - other than readability?

Comment: "Readability" suffices. (I first wrote the Python script on its own, not trying to do any shell quoting at all; then ran `pythonScript=$(cat <<'EOF'`, pasted it in, and added `EOF` then `)` on separate lines to do an initial assignment; then ran `declare -p pythonScript` to print a version quoted to eval back to itself, which is how I generated the code that went into the answer -- the point of that exercise was not to need to write correctly-quoted code by hand; letting the machine do it reduces potential for error).